# How to call another function within a function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, nested

I'm currently trying to detect duplicated sheet name using **"CheckSheet"** function. And I want to call this function to run in **"Add Sheet"** to prevent users from creating duplicate sheet names. However, I ran into error **"Compile Error: Expected function or variable"** and still not succeeding in solving the problem. Kindly enlighten me where I am doing it wrong and feel free to point out if there are any weakness and better optimization to my code. Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Public sheetName As Variant
Public cS As Variant

Sub CheckSheet(cS)  'To check duplicate sheet name - used in AddSheet function.
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    wsName = wS(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wS Is Nothing Then
    cS = False
    
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub AddSheet()
    Dim cSheet As Variant
    cSheet = CheckSheet(cS).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetName = Application.InputBox(prompt:="New Sheet Name", Left:=(Application.Width / 2), Top:=(Application.Height / 2), Title:="Add Sheet", Type:=2)
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name cannot be empty!"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf cSheet = False Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate Name! Please try again!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
        MsgBox """" & sheetName & """ was successfully created!"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You have `CheckSheet` defined as a `Sub` not a `Function`, so it cannot return anything. You are also missing an `End If` in `CheckSheet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

**1.** Your code can be simplified. You do not need a function to check if a worksheet exists.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheet()
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim sheetName As Variant
    
    '~~> Accept user input
    sheetName = Application.InputBox(prompt:="New Sheet Name", _
                                     Left:=(Application.Width / 2), _
                                     Top:=(Application.Height / 2), _
                                     Title:="Add Sheet", Type:=2)

    '~~> User presses cancel
    If sheetName = False Then Exit Sub
    
    '~~> Check if the sheet name is empty
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name cannot be empty!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '~~> Check if the sheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not sh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate Name! Please try again!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    '~~> Create the worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
        MsgBox """" & sheetName & """ was successfully created!"
    End With
End Sub
```

**2.** Even if you want to use a function, your code has lot of errors. (One of them is pointed out by @braX above.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub AddSheet()
    Dim sheetName As Variant
        
    '~~> Accept user input
    sheetName = Application.InputBox(prompt:="New Sheet Name", _
                                     Left:=(Application.Width / 2), _
                                     Top:=(Application.Height / 2), _
                                     Title:="Add Sheet", Type:=2)

    '~~> User presses cancel
    If sheetName = False Then Exit Sub
       
    '~~> Check if the sheet name is empty
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Sheet name cannot be empty!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    '~~> Check if the sheet exists
    If DoesSheetExists(CStr(sheetName)) = True Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate Name! Please try again!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
            
    '~~> Create the worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
        MsgBox """" & sheetName & """ was successfully created!"
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if sheet exists
Private Function DoesSheetExists(wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Object
        
    '~~> Check if the sheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    If Not sh Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExists = True
End Function
```

Comment: Both ways worked great, I like the 1st option better for it is much shorter and better organized. Works like a charm. However, I m curious if i can use if else condition continuously instead of many if condition instances.

Comment: Oh yes, you defintiely can use `If-ElseIf` to combine the first 2. in scenario 1

Comment: `Sheets.Count` is unqualified. It's either `DoesSheetExist` (without the trailing `s`) or `SheetExists` (English grammar). If you want the function to apply to all sheets, then you could replace `ws` with `sh` while `As Worksheet` should be replaced with `As Object` so when I have a chart called e.g. `Data`, it says that it exists (the suppressed error would cause the function to suggest otherwise). Just let me know when you've read it so I can remove it.

Comment: **1.** I agree about `Sheets.Count`. I will fix that. I missed that while copy pasting. **2.** Regardign the grammer, I usually do not care much when naming Procedures, Variables etc :) **3.** Another good point. Will add that. **4.** No please do not delete your comment. These are some good suggestions. @VBasic2008